# Transform Reactive Cocoa SignalProducer into enum

Tags: swift, enums, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to transform my API SignalProducers into an enum so I get Loading, Failed and Loaded states. Enum is:

```
enum DataLoadState<DataType>{
    case Loading
    case Failed
    case Loaded(DataType)
}
```

To do it I transform my SignalProducer to a NoError producer and start with loading state:

```
extension SignalProducerType{
    func materializeToLoadState() -> SignalProducer<DataLoadState<Value>,NoError>{
        let producer = self
        .map(DataLoadState.Loaded)
        .startWithValue(DataLoadState.Loading)

        return producer.ignoreErrors(replacementValue:DataLoadState<Value>.Failed)
    }
}

extension SignalProducerType {

    func startWithValue(value:Value)->SignalProducer<Value,Error>{
        return SignalProducer(value:value).concat(self.producer)
    }

    public func ignoreErrors(replacementValue replacementValue: Self.Value? = nil) -> SignalProducer<Self.Value, NoError> {
        return self.flatMapError { error in
            return replacementValue.map(SignalProducer.init) ?? .empty
        }
    }
}
```

It works but I don't want to ignore Errors, instead I want to include it in the failed case:

```
enum DataLoadState<DataType>{
    case Loading
    case Failed(APIError?)
    case Loaded(DataType)
}
```

Any idea on how can I use flatMapError (like in ignoreError) so errors are fired as DataLoadState.Failed(error) instead of being ignored? When error isn't display error is could be just nil. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed it just with:

```
producer.flatMapError { error in SignalProducer(value:.Failed(error as? APIError)) }
```